# How to create columns based on date in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, aggregation

I have DataFrame like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "1", "2"],
                   "Date" : rng,
                   "kind" : ["active", "not_active", "active", "active", "not_active"],
                   "status" : ["b2", "b2", "g8", "g8", "v10"]})
```

And i need to create DataFrame which will show what was the status of the last active and the last not active agreement. Below I upload example of result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If datetimes are sorted you can use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = (df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='kind', values='status', aggfunc='last')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

If not sure if sorted add [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (df.sort_values(['ID','Date'])
        .pivot_table(index='ID', columns='kind', values='status', aggfunc='last')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
  ID active not_active
0  1     g8        NaN
1  2    NaN        v10
```